# JavaFX NullPointerException in SystemProperties.setVersions()

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a legacy Swing application that is slowly being pulled into JavaFx.  The first goal was to create a new UI piece using the FX framework.  This piece works without issue except for a small null pointer that gets thrown and silently caught in the Java API code.

```
//Ugly workaround to init the FX toolkit
JFXPanel dummyPanel = new JFXPanel();

Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() 
{
    try
    {
        initFX();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
}
});
```

I get an exception thrown upon hitting Platform.runLater deeper in the Java API SystemProperties.SetVersion()

```
Thread [AWT-EventQueue-0] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
SystemProperties.setVersions() line: 81 [local variables unavailable]    
SystemProperties.lambda$static$29() line: 67 [local variables unavailable]  
12132846.run() line: not available  
AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>) line: not available [native method]  
SystemProperties.<clinit>() line: 64    
PlatformImpl.runLater(Runnable, boolean) line: 276  
PlatformImpl.runLater(Runnable) line: 265   
Platform.runLater(Runnable) line: 81
```

That function attempts to get the resource as a stream:
/com/sun/javafx/runtime/resources/version.properties

This however returns a null as it cannot find the version.properties file.  Digging into the jfxrt.jar it appears the structure only goes as far as com/sun/javafx/runtime, so the version.properties file simply doesn't exist, leading to this issue.

I've run this against Java 8u25 and the dec 31 8u40 beta.  In both cases I get the same null pointer behavior.  This exception ends up ignored by the API and causes no known issues, but it's still something that bothers me and I'd rather fix it.

Comment: That seems like a bug (though the workaround you are using looks suspicious; is there a way you can avoid having to bootstrap the FX toolkit in a non-standard way?). Can you create a simple executable example to reproduce it?

Comment: My code originally looked a lot like [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/swing-fx-interoperability.htm) but I ended up using a Stage rather than a the panel.  In an earlier incarnation very similar to the oracle example I still had the bug.