# JavaFX: Can't start program (Bug)

Tags: java, javafx-8

I previously created a JavaFx program taht worked at first quite good, but after a bit off time, i always get this error when I want to start the program. The Bug is the following:

```
Main (4) [Java Application] 
application.Main at localhost:49308 
    Thread [main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException))  
        SystemProperties.setVersions() line: not available  
        SystemProperties.lambda$static$28() line: not available 
        762152757.run() line: not available 
        AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction<T>) line: not available [native method]  
        SystemProperties.<clinit>() line: not available 
        LauncherImpl.startToolkit() line: not available 
        LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(String, String, String[]) line: not available    
        LauncherImpl.launchApplication(String, String, String[]) line: not available    
        NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
        NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available   
        DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available   
        Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: not available    
        LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(String...) line: not available 
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe (20.01.2016, 17:38:44)
```

The code:

Main class

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;


public class Main extends Application {

@Override

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Reader.setLanguageStrings();
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main_AnchorPane.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,960,740);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Reader class:

```
package application;



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Reader {

private static Locale user_language = Locale.getDefault();
private static CharSequence language_identifier;
private static String language = getLanguage();



@SuppressWarnings("resource")
public static void setLanguageStrings() {

    switch (language) {

    case "Deutsch":
        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Deutsch")));
            UI_Strings.Text_Stage = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Project_Menu = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_New_Project_MenuItem = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Open_Project_MenuItem = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Resourcepacks_Menu = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Import_Resourcepacks_MenuItem = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Manage_Resourcepacks_MenuItem = reader.readLine();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        break;

    case "Englisch":

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Englisch")));
            UI_Strings.Text_Stage = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Project_Menu = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_New_Project_MenuItem = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Open_Project_MenuItem = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Resourcepacks_Menu = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Import_Resourcepacks_MenuItem = reader.readLine();
            UI_Strings.Text_Manage_Resourcepacks_MenuItem = reader.readLine();

        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        break;

    }


}


private static String getLanguage() {

    language_identifier = "en";
    if(user_language.getLanguage().contains(language_identifier)) {
        return ("Englisch");
    }

    language_identifier = "de";
    if(user_language.getLanguage().contains(language_identifier)) {
        return("Deutsch");
    }

    return("Englisch");

}
```

}

In the class UI_Strings are only some deaclaration for Strings.

Main_AnchorPane.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.SplitPane?>


<AnchorPane fx:id="Main_AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <SplitPane fx:id="Main_SplitPane"

dividerPositions="0.6178861788617886" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" orientation="VERTICAL" prefHeight="740.0" prefWidth="960.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="25.0">

    <items>
            <SplitPane fx:id="Upper_SplitPane"                 dividerPositions="0.36116910229645094" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="200.0">

              <items>
              <TreeView fx:id="tree_navigation" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
            <AnchorPane fx:id="right_AnchorPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          </items>
        </SplitPane>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="lower_AnchorPane" minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="160.0" />
    </items>
  </SplitPane>
  <MenuBar fx:id="MenuBar" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
     <menus>
        <Menu fx:id="Project_Menu" mnemonicParsing="false">
           <items>
              <MenuItem fx:id="New_Project_MenuIttem" mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <SeparatorMenuItem fx:id="Seperator_1_SeperastorMenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="Open_Project_MenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" />
           </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu fx:id="Resourcepacks_Menu" mnemonicParsing="false">
          <items>
            <MenuItem fx:id="Import_Rescourcepacks_MenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" />
              <MenuItem fx:id="Mangae_Resourcepacks_MenuItem" mnemonicParsing="false" />
          </items>
        </Menu>
     </menus>
  </MenuBar>
```

This is only the bug, and I know a similar question had been asked before ([JavaFX NullPointerException in SystemProperties.setVersions()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27907359/javafx-nullpointerexception-in-systemproperties-setversions)), but I wanted to ask, if somebody maybe knows a workaround for this bug.

Thanks in advance!

I'm using windows7 64bit, java 8u60

Comment: Can we see the program?

Comment: If you comment out `Reader.setLanguageStrings()` and just set the static variables in `UIStrings` to some default values, do you still get the error? Also, I **strongly** recommend you read up on using resource bundles in [Java in general](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html) and specifically in [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#resource_resolution) for internationalization. There is so much that can go wrong with your code, e.g. files not available, etc. You don't even close the `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Just removed the resources and UI_Strings and Reader class for the moment but it still doesnt work :(

Comment: And I created a new javafx project that contains only the necessary code but still the same bug

Comment: The bug is not reproducible with the information you provided. Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).